# QED symbol in latex

Tags: latex

How do I type a QED symbol - I want a full box and not an empty box like `\qed` gives you. (I'm not using `\begin{proof}`)

Answer (score 73):

You can use [`\blacksquare` ■](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.#Electronic_forms):

> When creating TeX, Knuth provided the symbol ■ (solid black square), also called by mathematicians tombstone or Halmos symbol (after Paul Halmos, who pioneered its use as an equivalent of Q.E.D.). The tombstone is sometimes open: □ (hollow black square).

Comment: @ucortanbai FYI, "Use *x*." is a complete sentence. As for whether `_` (i.e. subscripting the ■) makes it look better is completely subjective matter. If you want to make that stand, do it in your answer.

Answer (score 72):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\backslash$blacksquare: $\blacksquare$

$\backslash$square: $\square$
\end{document}
```

You can easily find such symbols with http://write-math.com

When you want to align it to the right, add `\hfill`.

I use:

```
\renewcommand{\qed}{\hfill\blacksquare}
\newcommand{\qedwhite}{\hfill \ensuremath{\Box}}
```

Comment: Redefining `\qed` in this way seems to break `\qedhere` command. I prefer to redefine `\qedsymbol` instead.

Answer (score 11):

If you `\usepackage{amsmath}`, the `\blacksquare` command will typeset a solid black square.  The `\square` command will give you a hollow square.

The [`ulsy` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ulsy) has a few version of the lightning bolt for contradictions: `\blitza`, `\blitzb`, ..., `\blitze`.  Just drop `\usepackage{ulsy}` into the preamble of your document.

Finally, as others have pointed out, the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) is a great resource for finding the perfect symbol for the job.

Comment: don't forget $$. Should be $\square$ or $\blacksquare$

Comment: Actually you need to ``\usepackage{amssymb}``.

Answer (score 9):

Add to doc header:

```
\usepackage{ amssymb }
```

Then at the desired location add:

```
$ \blacksquare $
```

Answer (score 9):

As described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems#Proofs), you can redefine the command `\qedsymbol`, in your case - to `\blacksquare`:

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
```

This works both with `\qed` command and `proof` environment.

Comment: This is a rehash of previous answers.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It isn't. What I wanted to say is that the "correct" command to define is `\qedsymbol`, which is used by other commands and environments. What exactly you define it to is your choice.

Comment: If you make that clear in your answer - e.g. mentioning a name clash, as I suppose that's why you need this specific name (?) - then I'm happy to remove the downvote and comment; currently it is locked in.

Answer (score 5):

What about `\blacksquare`?   http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/Symbols.pdf

Comment: is there a reason this won't work? do I need to import anything? (`\square` works fine)

Comment: Oh ok ... \square in the link I gave you is a white square.  Thought you wanted a fileed-in square.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for this:

```latex
\newcommand*{\QEDA}{\hfill\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
```

Usage:

```latex
\begin{example}
  blah blah blah \QEDA
\end{example}
```

Answer (score 5):

`\rule{1.2ex}{1.2ex}` will give you a filled box.

`\fbox{\phantom{\rule{.7ex}{.7ex}}}` will give you an empty box. The `\phantom` command will typeset with invisible ink.

The advantage of this approach is that no package is needed. Also the size is up to your control. Less is more.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer:

In the preamble make sure you have `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Then in the preamble we can define this simple command: `\newcommand{\qed}{\hfill $\blacksquare$}`

Then whenever you want the QED symbol to complete a proof, you type `\qed`.

If you prefer a hollow square, replace `\blacksquare` with `\square`

Comment: This is a rehash of previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

The question specifically mentions *a full box and not an empty box* and not using `proof` environment from `amsthm` package. Hence, an option may be to use the command `\QED` from the package [`stix`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stix). It reproduces the character `U+220E` (*end of proof*, ∎).